# Get outside lightbox (modal box) after user logs in?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am sure there is a simple solution, I just need some direction.

I have button that says "login" when a user clicks it the backend portion of my site comes up in an iframed tab (the main site is in the root, the backend is located in /clients/ the index loads in the iframe)

So while I want the login portion (which is all in the index.php) to appear in the lightbox, I don't want the whole experience to be inside the lightbox... after the user logs in they are directed to account.php, unfortunately my problem is that while in account.php they stay in the lightbox.

What would be the solution to getting outside the lightbox to the full page after the login..

NOTE: I have tried this solution, with no success (maybe I did it wrong)

I put the following in the header.

```
    `<script language="javascript">
    function redirectParent()
    {
    window.opener.document.location("account.php");
    }
    </script>`
```

Then inside the index.php where the submit button is I put the following

```
    `onclick="redirectParent()"` <--- I added that inside the following below

     `<input name="submit" onclick="redirectParent()" value="<?php echo             lang('LOGIN_BUT_NOW');?>" type="submit" class="button"/>`
```

That did not do anything, I feel like I may be missing something simple here. If that is not the solution I am looking for, I would appreciate a litte nudge into the direction of the proper solution for what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.top.location.href = "account.php";
```

Comment: The function worked, but A. as soon as you click login, it redirects to clients/index.php it also does some weird loading loop the page just keeps loading over n over.

Comment: Here is some PHP code in my index, that might help some of you who are good at jquery or javascript..

       <?php  define("_VALID_PHP", true);
      require_once("init.php");

      if ($user->logged_in)
          redirect_to("account.php");

      if (isset($_POST['doLogin']))
          : $result = $user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

      /* Login Successful */
      if ($result)
          : redirect_to("account.php");
      endif;
      endif;
      ?>

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to redirect to the new page from inside fancybox but only close it after submitting the form. Use the `onsubmit` attribute on the `form` tag not in the `input` (submit) tag like :

```
<form onsubmit="parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();" ....
```

... then, in your fancybox custom script (the one you used to open fancybox) add the callback `afterClose` to redirect to the page you want like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
      window.location.href = "path/account.php";
        return;
    }
});
```